# How to Convert custom CSS Modal into Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a custom CSS maded Modal which I want to place in the bootstrap website template. Now the problem is this custom Css Modal wasn't fit into the theme and the css code of Modal interfere with the bootstrap classes and the result would be **shown here**:[image]

I want to convert the Modal into the bootstrap layout so that it would align perfectly with my bootstrap theme:

**This is how Modal looks like**:[image]

**Layout which looking in bootstrap:**[image]

**Here is the code for working Modal:**

```js
var popupdisplayed = false;
jQuery(function() {
    //----- CLOSE
    jQuery('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        jQuery('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.popup').show(0);
    var halfbrowserHeight = jQuery(window).height() / 2;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var distance = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (distance >= halfbrowserHeight && !popupdisplayed) {
           jQuery('.popup').show(0);
           popupdisplayed = true;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}

.popup-inner p a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f8f341;
    font-family: 'Yeon Sung', cursive;
}

.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    line-height: initial;
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:99;
    text-align: left;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#40434c;
    background-size:cover;
    color:#000;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding:4px 2px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:#1b1464;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

.mybtn {
    width: calc(50% - 60px);
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e42022;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.mybtn:hover{opacity: 0.9;}

.join{background: #1b1464;}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.right3 ul {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.right3 ul li {
    background-image: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/502ku2hsv/correct_sign.png'); 
    list-style: none;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: 15px;
}

.code{ color:#23B14D; font-weight:700;}

.left3 {
    width:40%;
    padding:0 10px 0 0; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    min-height:2px; 
    float:left; 
}

.right3 { 
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 310px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.left3 img {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.left3 {background:url('https://s33.postimg.cc/d5kms1ya7/player1.png') no-repeat center top / auto 100%; }

.right3 p { margin:0; }

.popup-inner {
    display:flex; 
    /*background: rgba(228,32,34,0.7); */
    background: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #e42022;
}

.preventclose {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:5px;  }

.left4{
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
    padding:0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bbtitle {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #1b1464;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.right4 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left; 
    color:#FFF;
    padding:0 10px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.popup-inner .left4 a {
    font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-inner .right4 a {
    font-size: 21px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

.firstlink {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 10px 10px;
    background: none;
}

.endtext {
 padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 21px !important;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.dollar25 {
    color:red;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.right3 p {
    padding:5px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.ifl-image{
    width: 80px !important;
}



@media(max-width:767px) {
    .left3 {width:30%;}

    .right3 {
        width:70%;
        height: 360px;
        padding:0 10px;
    }

    .popup-inner {
        max-width:600px;
    }

    .left3 img {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:550px) {
    .popup-inner {display:block;}

    .bbtitle {
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .left3 {
        width:100%; 
        height:200px; 
        background-size:cover; 
        background-position:center top;
    }

    .right3 {width:100%;}

    .popup-inner {max-width:400px;}

    .off {font-size:60px;}

    .left3 img {
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preventclose"></div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
<div class="popup-inner">
<div class="left3">
    <img src="http://intfl.com/themes/front//images/logo1.png" class="ifl-image">
</div>
<div class="right3">
    <div class="bbtitle">International Football League</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Want to win $100K?</li>
        <li>Want to win ownership of the IFL?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick team names?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick team logos?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick players for teams </li>
        <li>Want to help hire staff?</li>
        <li>Want to help fire staff?</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttons123">
        <a href="#" class="join mybtn">Join</a><a href="#" class="notnow mybtn">Not Now</a>
    </div>
    <p>Well there's no need to want anymore here's your chance. Just become a member of the International Football League for just <i class="dollar25">$25</i> to help call the shots.</p>
</div>
<a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I know the CSS but I have No knowledge about classes of the bootstraps.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the edited snippet - is that what you are looking for?
I've added CDN links to bootstrap 4 css and js to the head and made some edits of your code according to the suggested example in  [bootstarap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="left3"></div>
           <div class="right3"></div>
           <a class="popup-close" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">x</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}

.popup-inner p a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f8f341;
    font-family: 'Yeon Sung', cursive;
}

.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    line-height: initial;
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:99;
    text-align: left;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#40434c;
    background-size:cover;
    color:#000;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding:4px 2px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:#1b1464;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

.mybtn {
    width: calc(50% - 60px);
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e42022;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.mybtn:hover{opacity: 0.9;}

.join{background: #1b1464;}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.right3 ul {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.right3 ul li {
    background-image: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/502ku2hsv/correct_sign.png'); 
    list-style: none;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: 15px;
}

.code{ color:#23B14D; font-weight:700;}

.left3 {
    width:40%;
    padding:0 10px 0 0; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    min-height:2px; 
    float:left; 
}

.right3 { 
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 310px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.left3 img {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.left3 {background:url('https://s33.postimg.cc/d5kms1ya7/player1.png') no-repeat center top / auto 100%; }

.right3 p { margin:0; }

.popup-inner {
    display:flex; 
    /*background: rgba(228,32,34,0.7); */
    background: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #e42022;
}

.preventclose {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:5px;  }

.left4{
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
    padding:0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bbtitle {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #1b1464;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.right4 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left; 
    color:#FFF;
    padding:0 10px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.popup-inner .left4 a {
    font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-inner .right4 a {
    font-size: 21px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

.firstlink {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 10px 10px;
    background: none;
}

.endtext {
 padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 21px !important;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.dollar25 {
    color:red;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.right3 p {
    padding:5px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.ifl-image{
    width: 80px !important;
}



@media(max-width:767px) {
    .left3 {width:30%;}

    .right3 {
        width:70%;
        height: 360px;
        padding:0 10px;
    }

    .popup-inner {
        max-width:600px;
    }

    .left3 img {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:550px) {
    .popup-inner {display:block;}

    .bbtitle {
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .left3 {
        width:100%; 
        height:200px; 
        background-size:cover; 
        background-position:center top;
    }

    .right3 {width:100%;}

    .popup-inner {max-width:400px;}

    .off {font-size:60px;}

    .left3 img {
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preventclose"></div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="left3">
    <img src="http://intfl.com/themes/front//images/logo1.png" class="ifl-image">
</div>
<div class="right3">
    <div class="bbtitle">International Football League</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Want to win $100K?</li>
        <li>Want to win ownership of the IFL?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick team names?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick team logos?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick players for teams </li>
        <li>Want to help hire staff?</li>
        <li>Want to help fire staff?</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttons123">
        <a href="#" class="join mybtn">Join</a><a href="#" class="notnow mybtn">Not Now</a>
    </div>
    <p>Well there's no need to want anymore here's your chance. Just become a member of the International Football League for just <i class="dollar25">$25</i> to help call the shots.</p>
</div>
<a class="popup-close" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">x</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```